# How to get PHP code onto 1 line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello this problem is doing my head in but I am wanting to have the text that reads "Welcome back to ElectraNation, admin!" and then the dropdown menu that reads "Account" all on the one line instead of it dropping down onto the second line.

Here is my code:

```
<font size="2">
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<strong>Welcome, ' . $current_user->display_name . '!</strong>';
    echo '<li class="dropdown">';
    echo '<button class="btn no-padding btn-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down"> </i></button>';
    $args = array('theme_location' => 'topmenu',
        'container_class' => 'dropdown-menu',
        'menu_class' => 'menu-topbar'
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args);
    echo '</li>';
} else {
    echo '<strong>Welcome</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com"><font color="#9E0713"><font size="2">Login Or Register</font></font></a>';
}
?>
</font>
```

Many many thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "on to one line"? Are you talking about minifying? If not, it sounds like a CSS issue.

Comment: Onto one line so it reads like this,

Comment: There are a lot of issues in your markup, @Endo. You have an unnested `<li>`, you have `<strong>...</strong>` where you (likely) need to be using an `<h*>` element. Significantly, you are using `<font>...</font>` to set the font-size of the text, a technique which was deprecated quite some time ago. @mevius is right, this is a `CSS` issue. You will see that `CSS` styles have declarations like `font-size` (instead of `<font>...</font>`), `font-weight:bold;` (instead of `<strong>...</strong>`) and CSS `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` will result in horizontally adjacent elements.

Answer (score 5):

This is a purely CSS question. `<li>` is a block-level element. This means that it will appear on its own line by default...unless you style it to be floated, or display inline.

Also of note, your HTML syntax is invalid. You should wrap your list item in an `<ol>` or `<ul>` element.

Read more about [block-level elements over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).